# cypress-cucumber-preprocessor does not parse feature files

Tags: webpack, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have been trying to use cypress-cucumber-preprocessor with cypress to add feature of BDD.

I have followed the installation steps as mentioned in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#installation) but while running the tests I am getting the below error. It does not parse the feature files.

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
```

./cypress/e2e/login.feature 1:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/722#issuecomment-1147591083
I'm trying to solve this as well, I found this GitHub issue. If I am able to solve it I will let you know

Comment: Looks like badeball has published a fix here: https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/722#issuecomment-1153256645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue and it was because I had installed an old version of the package. Here's what you need to do:

```bash
# if you have the old version installed
npm uninstall cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

npm install @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor
```

You can find the [quick start document](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md) at the repository for the package. I am trying to use Vue3 with Webpack, so I followed the [webpack specific example provided](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/examples/webpack) which had me install the Cypress Webpack preprocessor:

```bash
npm install @cypress/webpack-preprocessor
```

This is where I had to do something differently. This repository is in Typescript but my current repository is not. So I converted the [TypeScript cypress.config.ts file](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/examples/webpack/cypress.config.ts) to a vanilla JavaScript configuration. This is what ended up working for me:

```js
// ./cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const webpackPreprocessor = require('@cypress/webpack-preprocessor');
const { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } = require('@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor');

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  const options = {
    webpackOptions: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.feature$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack',
                options: config,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },

  };

  on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));

  return config;
}

module.exports = {
  default: defineConfig({
    e2e: {
      specPattern: '**/*.feature',
      supportFile: false,
      setupNodeEvents,
    },
  }),
  setupNodeEvents,
};
```

Good luck—let me know if this needs clarification.

Comment: R Scott Could you help with this issue >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049214/migrating-cypress-test-from-old-version-to-latest-version-throws-error